# I'm sending POST to my webservice from postman and from my JS code - the response differ, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a webservice that returns a json based on input parameters.

In the software called `POSTMAN` I'm sending data with the following parameters:

```
{"deleted": "false", "nsfwPosts": "false", "anonymousPosts": "true", "publicContent": "true", "friendsNames": ""}
```

It gives me the desired result.

However, when I do it again, this time from my code:

```
var params = {};
params["nsfwPosts"] = false;
params["publicContent"] = true;
params["deleted"] = false;
params["anonymousPosts"] = true;
params["friendsNames"] = ""
console.log(params);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://mywebservice.com/...',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    data : JSON.stringify(params)

  }).success(function (response) {
     console.log(response);
```

then the console log brings empty result. What might be the problem here?

Comment: Does your webservice support CORS? From what I can see you are making a cross domain AJAX call here.

Comment: is it just a typo that you're missing closing `});` on the end of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first case you are sending `true/false` values as string. In second case they are Boolean.
Do like this

```
var params = {};
params["nsfwPosts"] = "false";
params["publicContent"] = "true";
params["deleted"] = "false";
params["anonymousPosts"] = "true";
params["friendsNames"] = ""
```

Comment: yes, that was my problem :O thanks man, I will accept it as soon as I can!